# Amazon SES OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, out-of-memory, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon's SES Android SDK in order to send large images using SendRawEmailRequest. Unfortunately, I'm always getting dreaded OutOfMemoryException since my application grows to about 60MB of memory space.

The images I'm trying to upload are 2-3MB in size, and I wouldn't like to have them resized.

Any way around this?

The code I'm using:

```
private void sendRawEmail(String content) {
try {
  Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
  MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
  mimeMessage.setSubject("Test");
  MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
  BodyPart p = new MimeBodyPart();
  p.setContent("<p>" + content + "</p>", "text/html");
  mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(p);

  File image = storageAccessor.getImage();
  MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  mimeBodyPart.setFileName(image.getName());
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
  DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(fileInputStream, Util.IMAGE_JPEG);
  mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
  mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
  fileInputStream.close();

  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);
  mimeMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
  RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();

  SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
  rawEmailRequest.setDestinations(Arrays.asList(prefs.getEmailUsername(id)));
  rawEmailRequest.setSource(SOURCE_EMAIL);
  SendRawEmailResult result = sesClient.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(result.getMessageId())) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

}

Kind regards,

Tomislav

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem arises from `storageAccessor.getImage();`

If this returns the uncompressed JPG this would give you a problem. An uncompressed JPG from format 2mb compressed on disc quickly accumulates to 50mb of RAM memory uncompressed.

See that you can find a way to fetch only the file and not the image data.

Comment: I tried with pdf file of same size and the same error is occurring. So I guess it's not the image problem (alone).

Comment: PDF expands in much the same way as JPG does.
Can't you simply fetch the binary file data?